# Leaflet err: Resource interpreted as Image

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I want to include leaflet map into my project but when I input my `setView()` I don't have a map, only empty layer with zoom buttons. I watched manual for leaflet [Quick Start Guide](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html) and there are no resons why my map doesn't work. I did all the instructions (added `div` and `css`, added my code (first in main.js file, then into tag `script`), tried to add map like in example).

I did my map in [mapbox.org](https://www.mapbox.com) and noticed a difference instructions written that `L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/MapID/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {` I need change only my `MapID`. When I did it I had an `error 401`

But in map box I have an export link like this: `https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/MaoID/page.html?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN#z/x/y`

I added it to my code and then I had a notice in console:

`Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: https://...`

How can I add this map into project???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where you got those URL's from but they are completly wrong:

```
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{mapId}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={token}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    subdomains: ['a','b','c','d'],
    mapId: 'myMapId',
    token: 'myUserToken'
});
```

Now you'll need to change `myMapId` and `myUserToken` with your own map's ID and your access token and you're ok. If you don't have those, you'll need to create an account on Mapbox: https://www.mapbox.com/signup/ to get a token and create your own map with the editor: https://www.mapbox.com/editor/#app to get a map ID. You could also just use `mapbox.js`, which is an extension of Leaflet, see: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/

Comment: It's more looks like a truth) And I still have an empty layer =( But I don't have any type errors or something. I can show you code maybe there are few mistakes